# Use Laplace’s equation forPDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

*This is italicized*

> How can i solve this PDE by using Laplace's equation?
>
> ${2*x*u_t }+{u_x}={4*x*t}$
>
> ${u(0,t)={t^2}+1}$
>
> ${u(x,0)=0}$

Answer (score 0):

$L\big(u(x, t)\big)=U(x, s)\Longrightarrow L\big(u_t(x, t)\big)=sU(x, s)-su(x, 0)=sU$. Thus taking the Laplace transform of the equation we get a linear equation for the transformed solution:$$U_x+2xsU=\frac{4x}{s^2}$$ with the integrating factor $e^{sx^2}$. 
After multiplying this factor we have $$\big(e^{sx^2}U\big)_x=\frac{4x}{s^2}e^{sx^2}\Longrightarrow e^{sx^2}U=\int\frac{4x}{s^2}e^{sx^2}dx=\frac{2}{s^3}e^{sx^2}+C\Longrightarrow U(x, s)=\frac{2}{s^3}+Ce^{-sx^2}.$$ Since $u(0, t)=t^2+1$, taking the Laplace transform implies that $U(0, s)=\displaystyle\frac{2}{s^3}+\frac{1}{s}$. Thus using this condition above we get $C=\frac{1}{s}$ and hence $$U(x, s)=\frac{2}{s^3}+\frac{1}{s}e^{-sx^2}.$$ Now inverse Laplace transform gives $$u(x, t)=t^2+H(t-x^2),$$

where $H(t-x^2)$ is a unit step function.